# What is meant by *const*a in c++

Tags: c++, constants

I am having a blocking trouble trying to figure out what it meant by the following 2 lines. following is a method declaration declared by gsoap and I am confused as to how I should define the parameters for the finstion

```
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 **soap_serialize_PointerTomss__MobileUserType**(struct soap *soap, mss__MobileUserType *const*a)
```

So I am trying following but can not figure out what is the error here.

```
 mss__MobileUserType const *mobile_user_type = setupMobileUsertype();  
**soap_serialize_PointerTomss__MobileUserType**(soap , &mobile_user_type);
```

what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Do not add extra asterisks into your source code for emphasis, instead use comments or explanation in your question.  As it stands, I can't tell whether there were originally any asterisks next to that `const` or not.

Comment: A pointer to a const pointer to a?  const_cast<> to the rescue!  :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: `const_cast<>` never rescued anything.

Comment: @BenVoigt Lol - so true...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Type *const* a;
```

`a` is a `pointer` to a `const pointer` to `Type`.

**C++ `const` qualifier applies to what is left of it, if there is something on the left, otherwise it applies to what is on the right**.

To make simpler consider this.

```
int a;
int* const p = &a;    // (1)
int** pp = &p;        // (2)   This is not possible since `p` is `const` pointer.
int* const *ppc = &p; // (3)   This is your case.
```

---

```
mss__MobileUserType* const mobile_user_type = setupMobileUsertype();  // (1)
mss__MobileUserType* const *mobile_user_type_p = &mobile_user_type;   // (3)

soap_serialize_PointerTomss__MobileUserType(soap , mobile_user_type_p);
```

Read [**HERE**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html) and [**HERE**](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html) for more about const correctness.

Comment: A remark: remember in C++ `const` qualifier applies to what is left of it, if there is something on the left, otherwise it applies to what is on the right.

Comment: @Haroogan Shamlessly copy pasted. :)

Comment: I like the method of reading pointers right-to-left, so: a is a pointer to a const pointer to an mss__MobilUserType.

Comment: So in `volatile const X`, the `const` applies to the `volatile` to its left, and not to the `X` to its right. _*grin*_

Comment: @user1131467: Hey, I know people that are constantly volatile.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are calling expects a pointer to const pointer
to (non-const) `mss__MobileUserType`.  The expression
`&mobile_user_type` is a pointer to (non-const) pointer to const
`mss__MobileUserType`.  There is no implicit conversion between
the two.  (It's also strange to have a pointer to const pointer
to non-const, but I don't know the library, so perhaps there is
a reason.  And it's also undefined behavior to have symbols with
two successive underscores.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your declaration is this:

```
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_PointerTomss__MobileUserType(struct soap *soap, mss__MobileUserType *const *a);
```

Then you need to pass the address of a const pointer:

```
mss__MobileUserType *const mobile_user_type = setupMobileUsertype();  
soap_serialize_PointerTomss__MobileUserType(soap , &mobile_user_type);
```

Comment: Which may not be possible.  If `setupMobileUserType()` returns a `mss__MobileUserType const*`, he'll need a `const_cast` in there somewhere.

Comment: @James: A `const_cast` would be wrong.  If `setupMobileUserType` returns a pointer to a `const` object, then he needs to make a non-`const` clone.  If you aren't the one who added a `const` qualifier, do not use `const_cast` to remove it.  Ever.

Comment: A `const_cast` would make it compile.  After that... you're probably right.  If there were no const anywhere, one might suppose typical C, and that the function doesn't modify the object despite that.  But as there are already some const, it's probable that they are significant, and that casting them away will cause semantic issues when the program executes.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration can start with a possibly cv-qualfied type-specifier, for example:

```
X
const X
X const
```

It can then be followed by zero of more ptr-declarators like:

```
*
* const
```

Each one specifies a pointer to the previous type.  The const in the ptr-declarator applies to the pointer, not to the type:

For example:

```
const X*
X const*
X* const
X const * const
X const **const***
```

Let's break down:

```
const X ** const*
```

This is:

```
const X - const X
*       - pointer to previous
* const - const pointer to previous
*       - pointer to previous
```

So it is a "pointer to const pointer to pointer to const X"

Comment: Five-* programming?  Holy *<!>*